Error: Using NeumannValue with NDSolve correctly
I am trying to solve for the 2D linear Poisson's equation numerically and compare my results with MATLAB code. With mixed boundary conditions which are periodic along x with the interval $0 < x < 2\pi$ and zero homogeneous Neumann along y with interval $-1 < y < 1$ so the attempt I have looks like:
    framesWEQ = 
    Table[Plot3D[
    uifWave[t, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] uifWave["ElementMesh"], 
    PlotRange -> {-.3, 0}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
    Mesh -> None], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/50}];
    (*test case from StackExchange website w/ "mixed" BCs*)
    (*2D Non-linear Poisson's with unmapped coord*)
    Lx = 2*Pi;
    A = 2*Pi/Lx;

    a = -1;
    b = 1;
    NN = 1; (*y^2 * Sin[3*A*x]+10;*)
    GradNGradU  = D[v, x]*D[NN, x] + D[v, y]*D[NN, y];
    (*exact source MMS*)
    (*build S term*)
    dndxdudx = D[NN, x] * D[v, x];
    dndydudy = D[NN, y] * D[v, y];
    nd2udx = NN * D[v, {x, 2}];
    nd2udy = NN * D[v, {y, 2}];
    (*NumS1 = dndxdudx+dndydudy+nd2udx+nd2udy;*)
    NumS = ((-3 *b *Lx^2 + 6* Lx^2 *y + 6 *b *Pi^2 *y^2 - 4 *Pi^2 *y^3 - 
         3 *a* (Lx^2 + 2 *Pi^2 (2*b - y) y)) *Sin[A*x])/(3 *Lx^2);
    reg = Rectangle[{0, -1}, {2*Pi, 
       1}]; (*reg=Rectangle[{0,-1},{2 Pi,1}];*)
    V = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[v[x, y], {x, y}] == 
        1/NN*(NumS - GradNGradU), NeumannValue[0., y == -1 || y == 1], 
       PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[x, y], x == 2 Pi && 0 < y < 1, 
        TranslationTransform[{-2 Pi, 0}]], 
       PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[x, y], x == 0 && 0 < y < 1, 
        TranslationTransform[{2 Pi, 0}]]}, v, Element[{x, y}, reg], 
      Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
        "MeshOptions" -> {"MeshElementType" -> "TriangleElement", 
          "MaxCellMeasure" -> 2 Pi/1000}}]
    Plot3D[V[x, y], Element[{x, y}, reg], 
     PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-1, 1}}, 
     MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]


This returns a bunch of errors with an empty 3D plot box. The solution I get in MATLAB looks something like:

How do I solve this correctly using the Neumann BCs? Thanks!
EDIT
As requested I am posting full details and information about my MATLAB solution. Solving for a Poisson's equation on the form,
$\nabla \cdot (n\nabla u) = S$
which also can be expanded as, $n \nabla^2 u + \nabla u \cdot \nabla n = S$.
Here, the choice of the exact solution $u(x,y)$ was,
$ u(x,y)= (1/6) y \left(6ab-3ay-3by+2y^2\right) \sin{A x}$
and $a=-1$, $b=1$, the exact solution was chosen so that $u_x(x,-1)=u_x(x,1)=0$ (i.e. Zero Neumann in $y$) and $u(0,y)=u(2\pi,y)$ (i.e. periodic in $x$) and for simplicity we set,
$n(x,y)= 1$
This way the source term has the form:
$S(x,y)= \left(\left(-3bLx^2 + 6Lx^2 y + 6b \pi^2 y^2 - 4\pi^2 y^3 - 3a\left(Lx^2 + 2\pi^2(2b - y)y\right)\right) \sin{Ax}\right)/(3Lx^2)$
Then I solve the system $\nabla^2u(x,y)=S$ iteratively in MATLAB and get the following for $0<x<2\pi$ and $-1<y<1$:

Now, the above MATLAB plot to me looks similar to the Mathematica result or am I confused? Is my choice of $u(x,y)$ and effectively $S(x,y)$ wrong for these specific BCs? Especially, I am trying to eventually solve for an arbitrary interval of $a<x<b$ and $a<y<b$ that satisfies the Neumann BCs in y and periodic BCs in x. Thanks.

Your usage for NeumannValue is obviously wrong. It should be part of the PDE. Please read the document of NeumannValue carefully by pressing F1. Also, for zero Neumann value you don't need to explicit set a NeumannValue[]  because it's the default setting. (This is mentioned in Details and Possible Issues section of document of NeumannValue. )

Some remarks: Matlab solution doesn't look periodic in x!  Your problem needs an additional DirichletCondition ( see NDSolve messages) to  make solution v[x,y]unique!

Change y-range inside PeriodicBoundaryCondition to  -1<y<1(not 0<y<1)

@Mathew77 Starting your iterative Matlab solver with the exact solution brings no new insight. Because your ansatz fullfills v[0,1]==0 it should be similar to the Mathematica solution!

The solution isn't unique, you need additional Dirichlet condition. Examplary I take v[0,1]==0.
NDSolve command with changed y-range (see my comment) follows to
V = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[v[x, y], {x, y}] == 
    1/NN*(NumS - GradNGradU) + NeumannValue[0, y == -1 || y == 1] , 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[x, y], x >= 2 Pi && -1 < y < 1, 
    TranslationTransform[{-2 Pi, 0}]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[x, y], x <= 0 && -1  < y < 1, 
    TranslationTransform[{2 Pi, 0}]] , 
   DirichletCondition[ v[x, y] == 0, x == 0 && y == 1] }, v, 
  Element[{x, y}, reg], Method -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> MaxCellMeasure -> 4 Pi/1000 }]

Plot3D[V[x, y], Element[{x, y}, reg], 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-1, 1}}, 
 MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]


This solution is easily adapted to changed  x,y-range!

Thanks! I chose this problem arbitrarily to have a zero Neuman BCs at u'(x,-1)=u'(x,1), however, it seems my choice of source term is not producing a unique solution. Sorry, I am trying to understand the difference between my MATLAB code and the Mathematica one. Why do you specifically, include an additional Dirichlet condition? Is there a way I could choose a different problem (source term) where I get a unique solution for periodic BCs in x and homogenous zero Neumann in y?

@Mathew77 If v[x,y] is a solution than v[x,y]+const is a solution too. That's why we need a Dirichletcondition to get a unique solution

@Mathew77 Please give some additional information about your Matlab solution. It seems to be nonperodic

I included some additional information regarding the MATLAB solution with the plot of the result I am getting. Thanks.
